# Get recently viewed products in magento home page

Tags: magento

How to get recently viewed products in magento.

I tried the following code also

```
 $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts();
```

in the file product_viewed.phtml

Comment: Check on this. It may worked.
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9876/including-recently-viewed-product-block-on-product-page-right-column

Answer (score 1):

1.Place code snippet below in any template u want to add

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('reports/product_viewed')->setTemplate('reports/product_viewed.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

2.Place code snippet below in any Backend cms-> page or static block

```
{{block type="reports/product_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml"}}
```

Replace template name, product_viewed.phtml with your site.

Comment: you can find the components of recently viewed product in your/theme/layout/report.xml 

    <reference name="right">
    <block type="reports/product_viewed" before="right.permanent.callout" 
    name="right.reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />
   </reference>